# replace Twitter link by Read more

Tags: iphone, webview, twitter

In my app I have a WebView Containing a Twitter account for and every tweet there is a link take you to a specific website

my question : ***can I replace the links of those webpages by read more ?***

Answer (score 0):

You can override the link itself so that when the user clicks, instead of it jumping to that website, it calls your method.

Create an instance of UIWebViewDelegate,and implement the method:

> "webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
>
> Sent before a web view begins loading
>   content."

...and return "false" when the link clicked is one of those external links.

Then, also, do whatever custom action you wanted to do - e.g. popup a new UIView that contains the "read more" content you wanted to display

Comment: hello thank you for ur answer all i want is how to replace something like this http://on.natgeo.com/gEkRJQ by read more

Comment: You've linked to a national geographic page with tonnes of stuff on there that has no obvious link to your question. Think about what you're trying to achieve, then write it down properly - you're currently not making any sense.